# Загрузить аудиофайл vk api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Необходимо загрузить аудиофайл с ПК в VK, используя vk api
Написал такой код:

```
file = {'file': 'music.mp3'}
data = requests.post(url=vk_session.method('audio.getUploadServer')['upload_url'], files=file).json()
data.update(
    {
        'artist': 'noname',
        'title': 'noname',
    }
)
vk_session.method('audio.save', {**data})
```

Возникла ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [301] Invalid filename
```

Понятно, что vk api ругается на некорректное имя файла. Убрал расширение файла (думал, что может ругаться на точку в названии), но ошибка осталась. 
Попробовал загрузить файл на https://vk.com/dev/audio.save через "пример запроса" и этот файл был успешно загружен.
Что не так в моем коде?

Comment: Пропринтуй file, потом кинь ответ сюда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` -  Это поле должно содержать mp3-файл в формате multipart/form-data.

```
request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'music': open(filename, "rb")})
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли разобраться :)

Comment: @Иван пожалуйста)